# Variable scope of callback function

Tags: node.js, callback

I'm trying to use callback function in node js so I pass variable and callback function like this:

```
if(true){
await this.serialNumber(customer, async serial => {
console.log(serial); // it's log 43435543
});

// I need to use that serial out of the scope of that function by passing it to this new function
await this.storeinDB(customer, serial);
}

// this is the function where pass variable to callback function
async serialNumber(customer, callback){
const serial = "43435543";
callback(serial);
}
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the other function inside the callback like. Since you're not working with `Promise` using `async/await` makes no differece.

```
if(true){
  this.serialNumber(customer, function (serial) {
    console.log(serial); // it's log 43435543
    this.storeinDB(customer, serial);
  });
}

// this is the function where pass variable to callback function
serialNumber(customer, callback){
  const serial = "43435543";
  callback(serial);
}
```